# How to allow the process to wait for more than 1 min to get the response in vue.js using axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a large file that needs to be downloaded from server using axios however the request gets killed after 1 min and the file doesnt get downloaded so I need the process to wait until it gets the response

This is for Axios in vue.js. Tried setting timeout value to more than 10 mins but that didn't help

```
        progress=0;
        this.$store.commit("routeChange", "start");
        this.progress = true;
        var timestamp = Math.round(+new Date() / 1000);
        var userip = '127.0.1';
        var data = {
              page: {
              startIndex: 0,
              size: 10000
            },
            days: 0,
            fromDate: "",
            toDate: "",
            mandateID: ""
        };
        var msgHeader = {
            authToken: localStorage.getItem('authtoken'), //dynamic
            authLoginID: this.$store.getters.loginId,
            timestamp: timestamp,
            ipAddress: userip
        };
        this.$root.$emit('component1',false);
        var mlShowMandateData = {data, msgHeader};
        const instance = axios.create();

        //increased Timeout value
        instance.defaults.timeout = 6000000;
        instance.post('mlShowMandateData', mlShowMandateData).then((response) => {
            progress = 1;
            const JSONData = response.data;
            if (JSONData.data.error == 0) {
                this.$store.commit('setauthtoken', {
                    authtoken: JSONData.msgHeader.authToken
                });
                localStorage.setItem('authtoken',JSONData.msgHeader.authToken);



                          });
                        }

                this.rows =  this.data.rows;
                //this.rows =  this.data.rows;

                this.$root.$emit('component1' , true);

            }
            else {

                });


            }
            this.$store.commit("routeChange", "end");
            this.progress = false;

        })
    },
```

I expect the process to wait for the response but it stops execution after 1 min

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1503

Comment: already tried it but its not working for me

Comment: already tried to check your server configuration?